# Filling in a Graphics3D object

Tags: graphics, wolfram-mathematica, 3d

Here is a problem that I don't know if can be solved in Mathematica.

```
(* Courtesy to Lunchtime Playground Blog *)
to3d[plot_, height_, opacity_] :=
Module[{newplot}, newplot = First@Graphics[plot];
newplot = N@newplot /. {x_?AtomQ, y_?AtomQ} -> {x, y, height} /. 
Arrowheads[List[List[x_, y_, notz_]]] -> 
 Arrowheads[List[List[x, y]]];newplot /.GraphicsComplex[xx__] -> {Opacity[opacity], GraphicsComplex[xx]}];
(* A function to combine 2D Graphics object in Mathematica *)
test[list_]:=VectorQ[list,SameQ[Head[#],Graphics]&];
My3DPlot[list_?(test[#]&),height_?(VectorQ[#,NumberQ]&),opacity_?(VectorQ[#,NumberQ]&),opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=Block[{a},a=MapThread[Graphics3D[to3d[#1,#2,#3]]&,{list,height,opacity}];
Show[a,opts]
]
(* List of 2D graphics *)
list=Table[ContourPlot[y+Sin[x^i+i y],{x,-3,3},{y,-3,3},Contours->15,ContourLines->False,ColorFunction->RandomChoice[ColorData["Gradients"]]],{i,{1,2,3,4}}];
(* List of heights where you want to place the images *)
height={-.5,0,.5,1};
(* List of opacities you want to apply to your 2D layers *)
opacity={1,.8,.7,.5};
(* The function inherits all the options of standard Graphics3D as they are passed through the Show command *)
My3DPlot[Reverse@list,height,opacity,Lighting->"Neutral",BoxRatios->{1,1,.9},Axes->True]
```

Now  this returns a cool picture like this one.[image]

Here my question is if it is possible to create a filling for this 2D layers using the same color functions as are used with in the contour plots for example? Target is to fill the hollow between these 2D layers with some **light** or **color** that continuously changes according to the neighboring layer color-function.

I hope this can be done in Mathematica but my limited knowledge in Mathematica graphics is making it a difficult hurdle for me.

Comment: There was an error in your code. The pattern test for opacity was missing a '?'. I've corrected that. I wonder how you lost it while copying it to Stackoverflow.

Comment: I always get into trouble when I paste code directly from MMA. While formatting you always need to align them in the right. I accidentally deleted that precious '?'.

Comment: I don't see what you mean by "filling" the voids.  If each of your current layers were an MRI scan, how would we infer the nature of the structures in the unscanned regions?  There seems to be a general discontinuity between what is happening at each of the layers. This is exacerbated by the different color functions.

Comment: @David Carraher The problem probably has no practical meaning other than trying to achieve a programming goal in MMA. My target was to fill the empty space between the four layers of contour plots with light,color or any possible filling directive that will have its color function defined by the neighboring contour plot (aka 2D graphics). Empty space closer to one contour plot will be filled with color function similar to that contour plot.

Comment: @David Carraher Then the color will gradually change to another color function once we approach the empty space closer to another contour plot which is created with another color gradient. One can think of Homotopy transformation for the color function reaching from one predefined gradient to another continuously. And that transformation will be caught by the filling or the coloring of the empty space.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible. `Texture` can be used to generate a 3D texture. The example given in the documentation:

```
data = Table[{r, g, b}, {r, 0, 1, 1/20}, {g, 0, 1, 1/20}, {b, 0, 1, 1/20}];

Graphics3D[
  {
   Opacity[1/3], 
   Texture[data], 
   EdgeForm[], 
   Polygon[Table[{{0, 0, z}, {1, 0, z}, {1, 1, z}, {0, 1, z}}, {z, 0, 1, 1/20}], 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> 
    Table[{{0, 0, s}, {1, 0, s}, {1, 1, s}, {0, 1, s}}, {s, 0, 1, 1/20}]]
  },
  Lighting -> "Neutral"
]
```

[image]

This simulates a volume by using a large set of planes. You can do the same. All you have to do is describe the 3D texture, which should interpolate between the planes you already have.`Blend` would be the function to be used here. For each pixel column in your cube the color varies as `Blend[{col1,col2,col3,...},x]`  with x going from 0 to 1 and coli the color of the pixel in the ith plane given by the contour plots.

The main problem will be that a 3D semi-transparant object with fuzzy color gradients is not something that visualizes very well.